# Crystal Report If else on formula

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I got an error for following formula on crystal reports.error is **The remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula**

```
Numbervar t:=0;
IF({GLTRANDE.GLTYPE} =1 OR {GLTRANDE.GLTYPE} =5 )Then
WhilePrintingRecords;
t:=tonumber({GLTRAN.CRDIFF})-tonumber({GLTRAN.DRDIFF})
//ELSE IF({GLTRANDE.GLTYPE}="2" OR {GLTRANDE.GLTYPE}="3" OR {GLTRANDE.GLTYPE}="4" )Then
else
WhilePrintingRecords;
t:=tonumber({GLTRAN.DRDIFF})-tonumber({GLTRAN.CRDIFF})
```

please give a advice for rectify this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making use of paranthesis and also add semicolon to the last statements of if and else

```
Numbervar t:=0;
IF({GLTRANDE.GLTYPE} =1 OR {GLTRANDE.GLTYPE} =5 )Then
(
WhilePrintingRecords;
t:=tonumber({GLTRAN.CRDIFF})-tonumber({GLTRAN.DRDIFF});
)
else
(
WhilePrintingRecords;
t:=tonumber({GLTRAN.DRDIFF})-tonumber({GLTRAN.CRDIFF});
)
```